# Using Apache Spark in poor systems with cassandra and java

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to use Apache Spark on my cluster which is made by 5 poor systems. At first I have implemented cassandra 3.11.3 on my nodes and all of my nodes are OK.

After that I have inserted 100k records in my nodes with a JAVA api without using Spark and all is OK too.

Now I want to execute a simple query like as follows:

```
select * from myKeySpace.myTbl where field1='someValue';
```

Since my nodes are weak in hardware, I want to get just a little records from myTbl like this:

```
select * from myKeySpace.myTbl where field1='someValue' limit 20;
```

I have tested this (A) but it is very slow (and I don't know the reason):

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = sparkSession.sql("select * from myKeySpace.myTbl where field1='someValue' limit 20");
```

and also (B) that I think Spark fetches all data and then uses limit function which is not my goal:

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = sparkSession.sql("select * from myKeySpace.myTbl where field1='someValue'").limit(20);
```

I think I can use Spark core (C) too. Also I know that a method called `perPartitionLimit` is implemented in cassandra 3.6 and greater (D).

As you know, since my nodes are weak, I don't want to fetch all records from cassandra table and then use limit function or something like that. I want to fetch just a little number of records from my table in such that my nodes can handle that.

So what is the best solution?

**update:**

I have done the suggestion which is given by @AKSW at the comment:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("SparkTest")
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","192.168.107.100");
long limit=20;
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> rdd1 = javaFunctions(jsc)
                    .cassandraTable("myKeySpace", "myTbl")
                    .select("id").perPartitionLimit(limit);

System.out.println("Count: " + rdd1.count()); //output is "Count: 100000" which is wrong!
jsc.stop();
```

but `perPartitionLimit(limit)` that `limit=20` does not work and all records fetch!

Comment: what does not work with the code above? I don't get the problem here

Comment: When I use (A), I have very slow execution! and I don't know the reason. In (B) solution, I think Spark fetches all data and then uses limit function which is not my goal! I'll be grateful if I make a mistake inform me...

Comment: well, see https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-31

Comment: and try this: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#limiting-rows

Comment: @AKSW thanks for your reply. I have done the solution which is given in the above links. I updated the question. Can you tell me the reason of the new occurred problem?

Comment: well, the limit is per partition key. how many partitions keys do you have in your Cassandra? Note, if the key is the `id`, it obviously will return all rows

Comment: @AKSW Thanks. Yes, my `uuid id` is my partition key. So this method can not help me because always return all records. How ever, what is the solution?

Comment: @AKSW Also, is `partition key` the first key(s) in the `primary key` in cassandra? If yes, so your question "how many partitions keys do you have in your Cassandra" is always all records!